# Merge Matching MySql results for XLS Export

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm working on adding an XLS Export for an ecom site to generate sales reports.

I've got it exporting fine from the first table `Orders`.

My Problem is that I'd like to add product details as well ModelNum and Quantity and they are stored individually on another table `OrderItemDetails`

I can retrieve this info using an INNER JOIN but it repeats all order info over.

What I'd like to do is instead of creating a new row in the xls for each product ModelNum and Qty I'd like to merge all products results into one column. For Example ModelNum1(3),ModelNum2(1)

The script I'm using to generate the XLS files requires the select statement in one var.

For Example

```
$q = "SELECT o.Date AS Date,o.AccountID AS AccountID, o.Status AS Status, d.ModelNumber AS ModelNumber, d.Quantity AS Quantity
FROM Orders AS o
INNER JOIN OrderItemDetails AS d
  ON o.ID = d.OrderID   
  WHERE o.Status = 'Paid'
  AND a.Type ='Shipping'
  ORDER BY o.Date ASC";
```

So my question is this "Is there a way to merge matching results into one column?"
Should I be using something other then INNER JOIN.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the group_concat function.

Comment: Sounds like what I want to be using. Seems to only load 1 row if I try GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.ModelNumber) AS ModelNumber

Comment: That got me in the right direction thanks! Anyone interested in the select statement I used it was: $q = " SELECT o.Date, 
          o.AccountID, 
          o.Status,
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.ModelNumber, '(', d.Quantity, ')' ORDER BY ModelNumber SEPARATOR ',') Order_Items,
FROM      Orders o
JOIN      OrderItemDetails d ON (d.OrderID = o.id)
WHERE     o.Status = 'Paid'
AND       a.Type ='Shipping'
GROUP BY  o.id";